# How to jsonResult on ASP.NET Webforms Like (webapi)

Tags: json, webforms, asp.net-web-api, jsonresult

i've a asp.net website (webforms), now i need to add some behavior on client-side, that will use ajax for simple operations.

in asp.net mvc webapi it is very easy to return a specific content class in json format, i just have to return the object and webapi does the work for me.

i've done something like this on the past with handlers, but it requires a lot of work.

is there some suggestions to get my "jsonResults" with asp.net webforms?

Comment: Just add a web API controller to your project.

Comment: ok, i'll try it. that is a website, not a webapplication, is the result the same?

Comment: I'm not sure.  Consider switching to a Web Application project.